# Asp.net Login providers by using Owin external login In a Pop Up Window

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, owin

I'm using MVC with Owin external login.

Owin doesn't open login as popup.
It redirects the page to that login provider.

For example
If i want to login through facebook it will not open facebook login in a popup window rather it redirects to facebook login page.

So far with my R&D i have found that I have to create an authentication provider for Facebook. So create a class that inherits from FacebookAuthenticationProvider. Within this class, override the "ApplyRedirect" method.

Here is my sample code :

```
public class FacebookProvider : FacebookAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override void ApplyRedirect(FacebookApplyRedirectContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&display=popup");
    }
}
```

and i wire this code in my startup.auth.cs class like this:

```
 app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new FacebookProvider(), 
            AppId = "xxxxxxxxxx",
            AppSecret = "647e05af9188a8a3ccd0793aae9a846f",
            Scope = { "email" },
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AppBuilderSecurityExtensions.GetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(app)
        });
```

and my _ExternalLoginListPartial.cshtml is like this:

```html
@using Microsoft.Owin.Security

<h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
<hr />
@{
    var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
    if (loginProviders.Count() == 0) {
        <div>
            <p>
                There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=403804">this article</a>
                for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
            </p>
        </div>
    }
    else {
        using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "CustomerAccount", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div id="socialLoginList">
                <p>
                    @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders) {
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
                    }
                </p>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

So if there is any way i can solve my problem.. i have spend like 5 days to solve this issue ..

Comment: What is the issue? if you can't use popups, then don't. Simply supply the `redirect_uri` param and facebook will redirect back to your app once flow is done. see [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4#login).

Comment: actually my requirement is to use pop ups

Comment: i have implemented with redirect_uri and its successfully done,..

Comment: was my suggestion helpful? if so, I will add it as an answer for you to accept it.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion .. and it dint fit on my requirements ..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I basically have the same situation right now without anything custom that I think you started to implement.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is telling Facebook to display the login page as if it was in a popup. You are not doing anything to *actually* display a popup.

If you were to wire your `button` tag `onclick` event to this function:

```
<button onclick="return loginPopup('@Model.MyUrl');">My button</button>
```

```
function loginPopup(url) {
    var w = window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {
        w.focus();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, we would be closer to have something working.